# Element li not allowed as child of element h1 in this context

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```
<h5 id="footer">Stephen Carter &copy; 2014 &middot;
    <li> 
        <a href="index.php">About &middot;</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contactform.php">Contact Form</a>
    </li>
</h5>
```

I get the error: Element li not allowed as child of element h5 in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

However, as you can see it is my footer. My footer looks like "Stephen Carter - 2014 - About- Contact Form".....The about and contact page has to be included within the header to be on the same line. How can I correct this so the error does not show? Thanks

Comment: `<li>` is only valid as a direct descendant of `<ul>` or `<ol>`. This means you will have to reconsider your markup — what is the purpose of wrapping list items within a header tag? It makes no sense.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/9es8m6wp/ something like this in horizontal line

Answer (score 1):

An `li` (list item) element can only be a child of a list element, either `ul`(unordered list) or `ol` (ordered list). Just put the `a` elements as direct children of the `h5` header.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer from @javier states, your list items need to be part of an ordered or unordered list

For the case of an unordered list:

```
<ul id="footer">Stephen Carter &copy; 2014 &middot;
    <li> 
        <a href="index.php">About &middot;</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contactform.php">Contact Form</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For the case of an ordered list:

```
<ol id="footer">Stephen Carter &copy; 2014 &middot;
    <li> 
        <a href="index.php">About &middot;</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="contactform.php">Contact Form</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Though you would probably be better just doing this html5 as you have stated that this is a footer:

```
<footer id="footer">
    Stephen Carter &copy; 2014 &middot;
    <a href="index.php">About &middot;</a>
    <a href="contactform.php">Contact Form</a>     
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a `ul` tag for the the li elements. Like this

```
<h5 id="footer">Stephen Carter &copy; 2014 &middot;
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <a href="index.php">About &middot;</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contactform.php">Contact Form</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</h5>
```

You can add a css code like this

```
h5 > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h5 ul >li {
    display: inline;
}
```

It must work like this.